# Make: recipe for target 'pcap-bt-monitor-linux.o' failed

Tags: debian, snort

I'm following this [guide](https://s3.amazonaws.com/snort-org-site/production/document_files/files/000/000/049/original/Debian___Snort_based_Intrusion_Detection_System.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIXACIED2SPMSC7GA&Expires=1442085807&Signature=sEUJyLA48d4Bhe9Jm1%2FQ98XkBzg%3D) to install snort on my Debian Linux. In step 2 while executing the command 'Make' to build libpcap I'm getting the error 'recipe for target 'pcap-bt-monitor-linux.o' failed'

```
gcc -fpic -I.  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -D_U_="__attribute__((unused))" -g -O2 -c ./pcap-bt-monitor-linux.c
./pcap-bt-monitor-linux.c:42:28: fatal error: bluetooth/mgmt.h: No such file or directory
#include <bluetooth/mgmt.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'pcap-bt-monitor-linux.o' failed
make: *** [pcap-bt-monitor-linux.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the problem is that you can't find the missing dependency bluetooth/mgmt.h.

A more direct way than those mentioned above to resolve your problem is to create a custom include directory in which you will copy the missing header:

```
# ${source_dir} is the dir where you're using make
# creating custom include directory
mkdir -p ${source_dir}/include/bluetooth

# downloading the missing header into it
curl https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/plain/trunk/mgmt.h?h=packages/libpcap -o ${source_dir}/include/bluetooth/mgmt.h

# Adding the custom include directory to the include path
export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I${source_dir}/include"
```

See if that works

Answer (score 3):

The message is telling you that you are missing a dependency to compile the application. Using `apt-file`, you can easily find which packages contains the relevant file:

```
# apt-file update
# apt-file search bluetooth/mgmt.h
linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common: /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/net/bluetooth/mgmt.h
```

The package name may be different depending on the version of Debian you are running.

Answer (score 1):

Make can't find a dependency. You either don't have the file (most likely) or you installed it in a non-standard place. Make sure have the bluetooth-dev package installed:

```
sudo aptitude install libbluetooth-dev
```

Edit: User @jordanm has a better, generic way to find the file you are missing, but if you are using wheezy it is in the [libbluetooth-dev](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/amd64/libbluetooth-dev/filelist) package.